# Why does The Confluent Schema Registry set default compatibility type as BACKWARD?

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

`BACKWARD` Compatibility Types requires updating consumers first. Otherwise old consumer might having issue processing data written in new schema.

Most use cases I have seen so far of Kafka are having more consumers than producers. Therefore updating all consumers seems a much harder tasks than updating all producers(if more than one).

On the other hand, with Confluent's Serializers, producer is one the registering new schema with Schema Registry, even with this compatibility check in place, there is nothing stopping registering new schema with `BACKWARD` compatibility type but potentially breaking existing old consumers.

Then my question is why does The Confluent Schema Registry set default compatibility type as `BACKWARD`?

Comment: I totally agree with you. I could not find any reason why consumers should be upgraded first by default. Anyway in case you want to configure the default value, you can always do it through the property "schema.compatibility.level" https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html#schema-compatibility-level

Comment: that property doesn't work for me. do you have any examples around it ?